# Am I able to play Civilization 5 offline?

Tags: civilization-5

I am looking to buy Sid Meier's Civilization 5 but I don't have a reliable internet connection, so how can I play offline?

Answer (score 7):

You can purchase Civ 5 on steam and play in offline mode. Steam will automatically put you in offline mode if an internet connection is not available.

Comment: Game should be started at least once though, while the internet connection is working. This also enables achievements in offline mode, but 2K Games are a bit bitchy about offline mode sometimes when they have never been started at least once. And one should also go deliberatly in offline mode while online. That ensures it works.